# R plotly x axes are cropped

Tags: r, bar-chart, crop, plotly, axes

Using R plotly I'm plotting a bar chart, my factors are quite long so I made this transformation on the x axe:

```
tickangle = -45
```

Thing is, now my factors are cropped:

[image]

Any idea on how to automatically select a height to my plot so my factors won't be cropped?

Comment: `layout(margin = list(l = 0, r = 0, b = 100, t = 0)` may help. See [here](https://plot.ly/r/setting-graph-size/#customize-margins-and-plot-size)

Comment: it way better but still a little bit cropped for long names, thanks!!

Comment: then increase the b(=bottom) argument

Comment: perfect, many thanks, please write an answer so i can validate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `margin` argument inside the `layout` function:

```
layout(margin = list(l = 0, r = 0, b = 100, t = 0)
```

where:
`l = left`
`r = right`
`b = bottom`
`t =top`